# Should you use IIFE with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, iife

It seems to be that if you are using RequireJS and you use `define` and `require`, then there is not point of using IIFE as well, since each module is already wrapped in a `define`/`require`. Is that the case?

In other words, does this code

```
define(['app'], function(app)
{
    app.run();
});
```

has any difference/advantage to

```
(function() { 

    define(['app'], function(app) 
    {
        app.run();
    });

})();
```

Comment: You mean aside from `"use strict"`? no.

Comment: @FelixKling, yes! Okay, I will remove the `use strict` to not cause any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `define()` function is in Global scope anyway, so calling it inside an IIFE doesn't make a difference at all and it's kind of redundant.

It would be different if you put code outside of the `define` callback but you shouldn't do that because each file should represent an encapsulated module.

The only time I can think of using an IIFE with RequireJS might be when I'm configuring my application by calling `require.config()` before initialization; but even then if I'm just calling `require.config()` and don't have any code on the outside, I still wouldn't use an IIFE.

In this example here there wasn't a need to use an IIFE: https://github.com/vasilionjea/bower-requirejs-starter/blob/master/local/js/main.js

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: One question. If I wanted to use `use strict;` then I would still have to include the IIFE right?

Comment: Not really because you can just add the **use strict** statement inside the `define` callback, which would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Okay makes perfect sense. Alright, thanks once again

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you don't need to use an IIFE with RequireJS but **sometimes you should.**

If you use the usual `define([... deps ...], function (...) {...})` format then you are only *reading* `define` from the global space and everything else you do is encapsulated inside the function you pass to `define`. With or without an IIFE, you can leak what you want to leak and keep private what you want to keep private.

The IIFE will typically be desirable if you are writing code that you want to be able to run with and without RequireJS. For instance, this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    function factory () {

        // Build our module...

        return something;
    }

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define([], factory); // AMD environment: call define.
    else
        window.Foo = factory(); // Otherwise, leak into the global space.
})();
```

Popular libraries (e.g. jQuery) often have code like this that allows using them with RequireJS (or another AMD loader) and with `script` elements. This is extremely common. Using the IIFE allows to keep the `factory` function out of the global space.